# MySQL query only works when strings don't contain numbers

Tags: mysql, mamp

Ok so the query is really simple:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM d WHERE a = ('x' OR 'y' OR 'z');
```

And that query works great, but if I were to query say, this:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM d WHERE a = ('x' OR 'y' OR 'z' OR 'x1');
```

No rows would be returned because of the number in 'x1'.

I'm using mysql 5.5.9, and I'm running a virtual server on my mac using MAMP (if it matters)

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Right syntax: `SELECT a, b, c FROM d WHERE a IN ('x','y', 'z', 'x1');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM d WHERE a IN ('x','y','z','x1');
```

OR

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM d 
WHERE a = 'x' OR a = 'y' OR a = 'z' OR a = 'x1';
```

Answer (score 1):

The right query is:

```
select a, b, c from d where a IN ('x', 'y', 'x1')
```

`IN` clause evalues an expression agains other results.
If your field a is a varchar, you should put all varchars in your `IN` clause

that query should work.
If you want to read about `IN`, see this [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm)